# C++ mistake in OpenGL frame

Tags: c++, frame

I am new to c++ and I started with code : blocks.
Today I developed my first console application ( it is working properly :D) then I tried to add a frame with opengl but I made a mistake. 
This is the code:
(this is the console application code)

```
       #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;
        int main()
        {
            int x;
                int y;

                cin >> x;
                cin >> y;
                cout << "Type 1 for add(+)." << endl;
                cout << "Type 2 for removal(-)." << endl;
                cout << "Type 3 for multiplication(x)." << endl;
                cout << "Type 4 for division(:)." << endl;
                cout << "To see the rest of the division of the two number type 5." << endl;
                cout << "To compare the two numbers type 6." << endl;

                int c;
                cin >> c;
                if(c == 1)
                {
                    cout << x + y << endl;
                }
                else if(c == 2)
                {
                    cout << x - y << endl;
                }
                else if(c == 3)
                {
                    cout << x * y << endl;
                }
                else if(c == 4)
                {
                    cout << x / y << endl;
                }
                else if(c == 5)
                {
                    cout << x % y << endl;
                }
                else if(c == 6)
                {
                    if(x<y)
                    {
                    cout << " first number is smaller than the second." << endl;
                    }
                    else if(x == y)
                    {
                        cout << " first number is equal with the second."<< endl;
                    }
                    else if(x>y)
                    {
                        cout << " first number is bigger than the second." << endl;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "\n\n\n\aOps,something was wrong, ensure that the                            characters you typed was all numbers and not anything else." << endl;
             }
     }
```

and this is the frame code

```
 #ifndef M___ENGINE_H
 #define M___ENGINE_H

 //(*Headers(M___Engine)
 #include <wx/frame.h>
 //*)

 class M___Engine: public wxFrame
      {
     public:

         M___Engine(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id=wxID_ANY,const wxPoint& pos=wxDefaultPosition,const wxSize& size=wxDefaultSize);
         virtual ~M___Engine();

         //(*Declarations(M___Engine)
             //*)

     protected:

         //(*Identifiers(M___Engine)
             //*)

     private:

         //(*Handlers(M___Engine)
        //*)

        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
 };

 #endif
```

and I am taking an error from codeblocks in the frame code in line 5 at the statement :#include

Comment: Cool story bro. So what's the problem/issue/question?

Comment: At your current level of C++ understanding, all of this is futile. You seem to be under the terribly wrong impression that any GUI or OpenGL functionality is part of the C++ language itself. Give it a few more weeks, *then* try to understand what libraries are all about, *then* actually try wxWidgets.

Comment: as i said i am taking an error in line 4 at the statment  #include <wx/frame.h>    p.s. didn't wrote the frame code i just installed opengl in my ide and the code was auto-written so i can't find wat is going wrong